# use prepend to wrap grape api method

Tags: ruby, prepend, ruby-grape

I use grape to build my api website, and I wanna add auto used log feature to my website so I used prepend in my Grape::API class this is how I did:

```
module GrapeExtension
 def get(paths = ['/'], options = {}, &block)
   #add log code here
   super
 end
end
```

and  add code where I use Grape::API,such as

```
class API < Grape::API
    prepend GrapeExtension
    #other code
    get '/info' do
     #function code
    end
end
```

but it seems that my code in GrapeExtension is not called when I request the /info api,why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `paths=['/']` with a generic path handler, like this:

```
module GrapeExtension
 def get(paths = ['/*'], options = {}, &block)
   #add log code here
   super
 end
end
```

Comment: it seems doesn't work and I found that even the **get** method in Grape::API will be called only once at the first time when website initialize,so I doubt is it the right place to add auto used log here @Ivan Zarea